# How to enable monetization for videos uploaded with YouTube Data API v3 php?

Tags: php, api, youtube, google-api

I have a youtube verified account. Default Monetization settings enable.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Va1u9.png

how to enable monetization for videos uploaded with youtube data api v3 php ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't unless you are a google partner. If you are, use the Content ID API and you can do this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/upload_claim_sample